# I want to map file1 column(1,2,4,5) to file2 column(1,2,4,5). 5th columns may contain comma separated characters (A,T,G,C) with different orders

Tags: awk, grep

file1

```
chr1 123896 rs0987522 A T
chr5 678452 rs8733521 G C,A
```

file2

```
chr1 123896 rs0987522 A T,C,G
chr5 678452 rs8733521 G A,T
```

output

```
chr1 123896 rs0987522 A T*,C,G
chr5 678452 rs8733521 G C!,A*,T
```

If 4th col of file1 is matching with any character is 4th column of file2 (A==>> T,A,G,C) then rows from file2 should be printed as given above in output and matching character from file1 (here T from 1st row column5) should be represented by "*" (T*)and non-matching character from file1 should be represented by "!" (C!).

```
awk 'NR==FNR{firstfile[$1,$2,$4];next} ($1,$2,$4) in firstfile' File1 file2
```

I have used awk but only for (1,2,4) columns. Kindly help for the 5th one matching.
5th columns comma separated characters may have different orders in file1 & file2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$1,$2,$4]=$5
  next
}
{
  val=""
  delete arr2;delete arr3;delete arr4;delete arr5 
  num1=split(arr1[$1,$2,$4],arr2,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){ arr4[arr2[i]] }
  num2=split($NF,arr3,",")
}
(($1,$2,$4) in arr1){
  for(i=1;i<=num2;i++){
    val=(val?val ",":"")(arr3[i] in arr4?arr3[i]"*":arr3[i]"!")
    if(arr3[i] in arr4){ arr5[arr3[i]] }
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){
    if(!(arr2[i] in arr5)){
      val=val "," arr2[i]
    }
  }
  $5=val
}
1
' Input_file2  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                            ##Checking FNR==NR which will be true when file2 is being read.
  arr1[$1,$2,$4]=$5                                 ##Creating arr1 with index of 1st, 2nd and 4th field and value of 5th field.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=""                                            ##Nullifying val here.
  delete arr2;delete arr3;delete arr4;delete arr5   ##Deleting arrays here.
  num1=split(arr1[$1,$2,$4],arr2,",")               ##Splitting arr1 with index of $1,$2,$4 here to arr2.
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){ arr4[arr2[i]] }             ##Running loop till num1, creating arr4 with value of arr2 index of i here.
  num2=split($NF,arr3,",")                          ##Splitting current line last field to arr3 with separator of comma here.
}
(($1,$2,$4) in arr1){                               ##Checking if $1,$2,$4 of current line are present in arr1 then do following.
  for(i=1;i<=num2;i++){                             ##Running for loop till num2 here.
    val=(val?val ",":"")(arr3[i] in arr4?arr3[i]"*":arr3[i]"!") ##Creating val which compares values of file1 and file2 is they are common then add * or add ! of file1 current value(one of the 5th field values).
    if(arr3[i] in arr4){ arr5[arr3[i]] }            ##If arr3 value is present in arr4 then create arr5 with index of value of arr3 with index of i.
  }
  for(i=1;i<=num1;i++){                             ##Running loop till value of num1 here.
    if(!(arr2[i] in arr5)){                         ##If value of arr2 is NOT present in arr5(to get values which are already printed common ones of file1, file2) then do following.
      val=val "," arr2[i]                           ##Append arr2 value to val.
    }
  }
  $5=val                                            ##Assign val to 5th field here.
}
1                                                   ##Printing edited/non-edited line here.
' Input_file2  Input_file1                          ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk` that stores `$5` with key as `($1,$2,$4)`. While processing file2 it splits stored value by comma and substitutes each comma separated value by appending `*`. If an element is not found (i.e. `sub` returns `0`) then we prepend each value by adding `!,`:

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR {
   map[$1,$2,$4] = $5
   next
}
($1,$2,$4) in map {
    n = split(map[$1,$2,$4], a, /,/)
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
       if (sub(a[i], "&*", $5) == 0)
          $5 = a[i] "!," $5
} 1' file1 file2

chr1 123896 rs0987522 A T*,C,G
chr5 678452 rs8733521 G C!,A*,T
```